# Why my data can not transfer between forms with SIGNAl/SLOT?

Tags: c++, qt

I have main window and 1 dialog in Qt(in Linux OS).I want to send some thing from main window to my dialogs. When the user press menu button, then my button clicked emit a signals. this is my code  in main.cpp:

```
MainWindow w;
MyDialog m;
//------------------------------
//this connection send key button press mood from MainWindow
QObject::connect(&w,SIGNAL(pressMood(QString)),
          &m,SLOT(getPressMood(QString)));
w.show();
```

and this is my mainwindos.h:

```
signals:
    void pressMood(QString mood) ;
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnMenu_clicked()
{
    if(database->checkEmpty())
    {
        menu mn;/*=new menu();*/
        mn.showFullScreen();
    }
    else
    {
       MyDialog *d=new MyDialog(this);

       d->show();
       d->raise();
       d->activateWindow();
emit pressMood("menu");
       if(d->Accepted>0)
       {
           if(loginResult)
           {
               menu *mn=new menu();
               mn->showFullScreen();
           }
       }
       else
           QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Login failed"), "Sorry.Your authenticate is not valid.", QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------
void MainWindow::on_btnPassword_clicked()
{
    //emit sendID2(result);
    CardDialog *d=new CardDialog(this);
     emit pressMood("pass");
    d->show();
    d->raise();

    if(d->Accepted<=0)
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Login failed"), "Sorry.Your authenticate is not valid.", QMessageBox::Ok);

}
```

I do not use `dialog.exec()` because I do not need to show modal.
MyDialog.h:

```
public slots:
    void getPressMood(QString mood);
```

and MyDialog.cpp:
//=================================================

```
void MyDialog::getPressMood(QString mood)
{
    mood=mood;
   //ui->lblMood->setText(mood);;
   //ui->lblMood->hide();
}
void MyDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    //QString mood=ui->lblMood->text();
    bool st=database->checkPassword(ui->txtID->text(),ui->txtPass->text(),"3");
    int id=(ui->txtID->text()).toInt();
    //this user is valid to go to menu page
    //s/he is admin
    if((st)&&
            mood=="menu" &&
            database->checkAdmin(id))
    {
         .......
    }
```

when I trace my code line by line. the emit signal is works , it sends the string data to my slot in another form and also the `getpressedmood()` slot is also worked. But the global var mood become NULL when the dialog show, also I decide to save data in label. In trace mood I see the string is send but when the dialog shows the label becomes to default value.
I can not find the mistake. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved.
my mistake is connect the signal and slot in main.cpp. The answer is :

```
    MyDialog *d=new MyDialog(this);
//should connect here not in main.cpp
           QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(pressMood(QString)),
                          d,SLOT(getPressMood(QString)));
           emit pressMood("menu");
           d->show();
           d->raise();
           d->activateWindow();
```